# In what sense can the $n$-dimensional "Principal Axis Theorem" be proved?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections

I have often seen it stated that a symmetric real-valued matrix $A$ acts on the unit circle $x^T x = 1$ by mapping it to $x^TAx = 1$, and that the resulting ellipsoid (which is defined by such quadratic forms) has as its principal axes the eigenvectors of $A$, with lengths related to the corresponding eigenvalues.

For a two-dimensional ellipse where $A$ involves no rotation, such a statement can be proved because the axes of the ellipse are defined/proved to be what they are in terms of classical Euclidean plane geometry. However, I have never seen a proof of the general $n$-dimensional case, rather it is defined that the principal axes of the ellipse are defined by the eigenvectors.

So if one were to take the statement that "the principal axes of an ellipsoid are the eigenvectors of $A$" as a definition, in what way can one corroborate this geometrically?

Comment: It's clear what the first principal axis is - it's the direction in which the ellipsoid is largest. The other principal axes can be defined to bw the directions in which the ellipsoid is largest which are orthogonal to the first $k$ principal axes; then you are basically proving the spectral theorem.